# Centos RES memory keep increasing and crossed initial and maximum memory for java

Tags: java, linux, garbage-collection

We have a java application running on Centos 6.4 what we notice is that the RES is around 378m which is more then the allocated max that is 256m. Does this signify that we the application is leaking? So far there is no GC happening yet but many YGC? What does this indicate?

Below is my jstat results and also the MAT results.

```
Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
      2331438.3  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331443.3  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331448.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331453.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331458.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331463.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331468.4  56.95   0.00  62.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331473.4  56.95   0.00  63.24  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331478.4  56.95   0.00  63.24  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331483.4  56.95   0.00  63.78  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331488.4  56.95   0.00  63.78  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331493.4  56.95   0.00  63.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331498.4  56.95   0.00  63.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
      2331503.4  56.95   0.00  63.79  82.79  80.37   1362   54.337     0    0.000   54.337
```

MAT Results

```
java.lang.ref.Finalizer @ 0xf5e19670 40 92,688 
next java.lang.ref.Finalizer @ 0xf5e1a6a8 40 93,024 
next java.lang.ref.Finalizer @ 0xf5e1bda0 40 122,768 


Suspect 1.

The class "java.lang.ref.Finalizer", loaded by "<system class loader>", occupies 1,337,176 (30.93%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.ref.Finalizer" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
java.lang.ref.Finalizer


Suspect 2
 6 instances of "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection", loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xf58bf000" occupy 432,624 (10.01%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:

•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf61c54f8 - 94,864 (2.19%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf61c4678 - 86,600 (2.00%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf61c4bf8 - 85,456 (1.98%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf626c348 - 68,000 (1.57%) bytes. 
•com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection @ 0xf626c7d0 - 68,000 (1.57%) bytes. 


Keywords
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader @ 0xf58bf000
```

Answer (score 1):

`-Xmx` limits only heap memory space for JVM
Besides heap space JVM is allocating memory for

- Perm space (class metadata) up to 64 MiB by default
- Thread stacks (256k per thread, configurable)
- I/O buffers and off-heap buffers explicitly allocated by application

Comment: so is this normal behaviour for the RES to grow? When you say heap isnt that my java programme should be operating withing the heap memory?

Comment: 378MiB for -Xmx256m seems to be adequate. If it would grow to, say, 1GiB that is a likely to be a problem.

Comment: Java code is operating in heap. But JVM itself is using additional memory. Java code also could allocate memory outside of heap using NIO API (though this off-heap memory is also limited).

Comment: before the likely problem occur could I do some analysis usue jstat or any other tool to find any indication of what is going wrong before it crash ?

Comment: any tool I should be applying here ? Thank you.

Comment: JVM usually crash when heap limit is reached. RES will be somewhat larger, but it is ok. You can monitor heap usage using jstat or JMX based monitoring.

Comment: I have edited my question with both my jstat results and also from the MAT heap analysis the suspesct 2 I think is pretty much due to the fact I am doing connection pooling is the first one I am having issue.

Comment: any tips on what should I be doing my application is multithread and lots of are being created too.